# How does rotation appear in the components of the angular momentum operator?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, angular-momentum, definition, textbook-erratum

In Hall's *Quantum Theory for Mathematicians,* Chapter 17, page 369, he introduces the angular momentum operator as $\hat{J} = X \times P$ whose the third component is
$$\hat{J}_3 = X_1P_2 - X_2P_1.$$
Promoting the right hand side to operators:
$$X_i \rightarrow x_i\\
P_i \rightarrow -i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$$
I would expect $\hat{J}_3$ to be
$$(\hat{J}_1\psi)(x) = -i\hbar\Big(x_1\frac{\partial}{\partial x_2} - x_2\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}\Big)\psi(x)$$
however in Hall's book he instead has that
$$\begin{align}(\hat{J}_1\psi)(x) =& -i\hbar\Big(x_1\frac{\partial}{\partial x_2} - x_2\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}\Big)\psi(x)\tag{17.1}\cr \color{red}{-}& i\hbar\frac{d}{d\theta}\psi(R_\theta x)\Big|_{\theta = 0}\tag{17.2}\end{align}$$
where $R_\theta$ denotes a counterclockwise rotation by angle $\theta$ in the $(x_1, x_2)$ plane. Where is this extra term coming from?

Comment: This is a misprint, I think. There should be an equal sign; angular momentum operators are generators of rotation. See e.g. [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/491530/equivalent-definitions-of-total-angular-momentum).

Comment: @TobiasFünke Thank you, it did not occur to me that it might be a typo. I checked the errata and you are correct.